# How to install a golang package during vagrant provision?

Tags: ubuntu, go, vagrant, provisioning, vagrant-provision

There are similar questions about how to install golang with vagrant provision or how to set `$GOPATH` environment variable, such that it will be available on boot.

However, this question is about how you can set `$GOPATH`, etc, such that the variable is available *during later steps of the provisioning script* (and everything else important about golang is in-place for that matter). I'm using an ubuntu image.

Specifically, I want to run these steps in `my_provision.sh`:

`go get github.com/saymedia/terraform-s3-dir`
`go install github.com/saymedia/terraform-s3-dir`

such that when I run the following command after `vagrant ssh`, it will just work:

`terraform-s3-dir`

When the go get/install commands run in `my_provision.sh`, it outputs one of two things: silence, or complaints that the `GOPATH` var is not set. Either way, when I boot in, `terraform-s3-dir` is not a recognised command.

I've tried setting the `GOPATH`, `GOROOT` and `PATH` variables in several different ways:

Setting them in `my_provision.sh` directly (with and without `export`), echoing export commands into .bashrc. echoing exporting commands to /etc/profile.d/gopath.sh. These all results in "$GOPATH not set".

running exports in an inline provisioning script, prior to `my_provision.sh`. This resulted in silent failure, unless I try to run the go get/install commands with sudo, in which case it has the `$GOPATH` error, too.

If I echo the GOPATH variable in `my_provision.sh` immediately before the go get/install commands, the variables show that they are set as expected.

If I run the go get/install commands manually from the shell after `vagrant ssh`, then it installs successfully.

What is different about the `vagrant ssh` context, vs the provisioning script context, where the go get/install commands get the desired result in the former, but not the latter?

Comment: How do you set them in `my_provision.sh`? Do you `export` them? `.bashrc` won't work unless you `source` it explicitly (since it's run only when a new bash shell is started)

Comment: @zerkms updated question to answer this

Comment: If you `export` a variable in the script that runs other `go` commands - those totally must be able to see them. (and it works without issues here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having is that in the context of the provisioning script, `$HOME` refers to the `/root/` folder, rather than `/home/ubuntu/`

It pays to NOT rely on the `$HOME` variable when setting environment variables during provisioning, if you want to use those variables later in the provisioning scripts.

Here is my solution (from `VagrantFile`)

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    echo -n                                          >  /etc/profile.d/gopath.sh
    echo 'export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go'                 >> /etc/profile.d/gopath.sh
    echo 'export GOPATH=/home/ubuntu/go'             >> /etc/profile.d/gopath.sh
    echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin' >> /etc/profile.d/gopath.sh
SHELL
devbox.vm.provision "shell", path: "scripts/my_provision.sh"
```

After this, this `GOPATH` is picked up correctly by `go get` and `go install`